# Fails to build android project with cmd

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to build an Android project using command line. I `cd` into the project's directory and tried `.\gradlew assembleDebug` and also `.\gradlew build` however I keep getting this error:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.

        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:161)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:137)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.doStartDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:204)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:128)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:138)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:290)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:263)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:256)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:190)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

My Java version is:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
java version "1.8.0_221"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_221-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.221-b11, mixed mode)
```

Gradlew version is:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-02-05 13:22:49 UTC
Revision:     37007e1c012001ff09973e0bd095139239ecd3b3

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_221 (Oracle Corporation 25.221-b11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 x86
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix this? I want to try and run this project using command line only and not to use Android Studio for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Java error. Looks like you are using a 32bit VM which cannot have more than 2GB of memory allocated.

Try switching to a 64bit JVM.